# How to make custom laravel.log file with custom name?

Tags: laravel

How can I in laravel 9 app to make custom laravel.log file with custom name, depending on APP_NAME, as I want
to distinguish these log files ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? The documentation suggests to choose the log file by creating an [on demand channel (Laravel Logging docs)](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/logging#on-demand-channels). You can store the return of the `::build` call in a member variable or some global object / helper I presume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use single or daily driver, you can change path in config/logging file like this:

```
'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path("logs/". env("APP_NAME") .".log"),
        'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
        'days' => 14,
        'replace_placeholders' => true,
    ],
```